# How is my AS3 class passing 0 arguments even though I specified one?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So basically; I was working on a test Game project in ActionScript 3 and decided to make a class that acts as a projectile of sorts.

This is the code for the class:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Symbol1 extends MovieClip {

        public var dir:Number;

        public function Symbol1(dir:Number) {
            // constructor code
            this.dir = dir;
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, speen);
        }
        public function speen(e:Event):void
        {
            e.target.x += 10*Math.cos(e.target.dir);
            e.target.y += 10*Math.sin(e.target.dir);
        }
    }

}
```

The above seems to work; But instantiating it is a whole new issue.

`var a = new Symbol1(5);`

The above code outputs:

```
> ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Symbol1(). Expected 1, got 0.
at flash.display::Sprite
/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at PROJECT_fla::MainTimeline()
```

How am I supposed to get it to pass the "dir" Argument?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't put an instance of that **Symbol1** anywhere on stage in design mode?

Answer (score 0):

For starters: simply drop whole "e.target" in speen, because your EnterFrame Event has no x, y and no dir in it.

Comment: You are correct about the dropping **e.target** part, because **speen** is a bound method, hence it operates within the same instance context, thus addressing self via **Event.target** reference is an overkill. Still, **Event.target** property is declared as **Object** so there shouldn't be any compile-time errors, and as long as **Event.target** contains a reference to something that really has **x**, **y** and **dir** properties, there should not be a runtime problem either. Basically, it is not syntactically or logically wrong, just pointlessly overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an instance of Symbol1 somewhere in your fla and present in the scene. That error is not triggered by "var a = new Symbol1(5);" but by  the symbol that exists sw already.